# How can I use Angular to hide an image until it has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to dynamically generate images. I want to hide or show a placeholder for each `<img>` element until it loads. Can I do this in my html or or can it be done in my controller?

```
<script>
    $http(info)
        .success(function(data){
            var response = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.paintings = response;
        })
</script>

<div class="group" ng-repeat="painting in paintings">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="{({ painting.fields.link })}"><img src="{({ painting.fields.link })}" /></a>
        <h3> {({ painting.fields.title })} </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a directive on each image and use a load handler in directive to show the element

Comment: @charlietfl Any directive in particular? I think a load handler is exactly what I need but I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an onload function for the image?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function runFunction() {
    $http(info)
        .success(function(data){
            var response = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.paintings = response;
        })
    }
</script>

<div class="group" ng-repeat="painting in paintings">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="{{ painting.fields.link }}"><img src="{{ painting.fields.link }}" onload="runFunction()" /></a>
        <h3> {{ painting.fields.title }} </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't arbitrarily us `$http` in global namespace ... will throw errors. Approach is a really bad hack in angular methodology

Answer (score 0):

You can initially hide the required divs and then show them when image is loaded. Jquery has image on-load function.

**Edit:** Code is updated

```
<script>
    $http(info)
        .success(function(data){
            var response = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.paintings = response;
        })

    // Let's show the div if id is found.
    function showImageDiv (imageDivID) 
    {
        $('#' + imageDivID).show();
    }

</script>

<div class="group" ng-repeat="painting in paintings">
    <!-- Initially set the display = none and add a ID to the div using index value  -->
    <div id="img{{$index}}" class="image" style="display:none">
        <a href="{({ painting.fields.link })}">
             <!-- On Image Load, let's call function by passing the ID of the div -->
             <img src="{({ painting.fields.link })}" onload="showImageDiv(img{{$index}})" />
        </a>
        <h3> {({ painting.fields.title })} </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: How do I initially hide the required divs and then show them when the image is loaded?

Comment: Simply on page load, just hide the div via code. For example,
<div class="image" style="display:none;"> should work for you.

Comment: I have that, but when it is time to ng-repeat a series of image divs, nothing happens, I haven't been able to show the images.

Comment: I just gave the hint about how to do it. :) I will update it with working solution at the end of my day.

Comment: @edmund_spenser I have updated the code. I hope it should work for you. Let me know if you face difficulty.

Comment: The function call in the `onload` method is not working. It is unable to pass the `{({$index})}` variable as an argument. I tested it with an alert() also and got nothing. Is it possible that angularjs variables cannot be used inside an `onload` method?